# Android APK Expansion Files. What files I need to upload?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have read all the documentation about [APK Expansion](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) for Android.

I have a simple question:
I have an application that is about 5mb of code and has 40mb of assets files. These assets files will be updated in further release of the app, so I have implemented the APK Expansion.
Now, I have to publish the apk and the obb files on the google play console.
Documentation says that "main" must be used for files necessary to run the app, and "patch" for optional files. In my case my assets file are optionals and will be updated togheter with the app apk code change, so what files I need to upload?

- The apk and a file zip named main.<expansion-version>.<package-name>.obb ?
- The apk and a file zip named patch.<expansion-version>.<package-name>.obb ?
- Or the apk and file zip containing both the two files? In this case which name I had to use?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the apk and the zip with .zip extension. Google play console will convert to .obb format, you don't need to care about it.

Comment: I already knew about the extension. The question is if I had to upload apk + main.zip + patch.zip